# Calling C# Unity Script from Android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have been trying to communicate with my Unity C# script through my Android Application using 
"UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("Cube", "Test","HELLO") - where "Cube" is my Unity Object, "Test" is the name of the method present in the C# script it is using and "HELLO" is the message String I want to pass.

This line is placed in my onClick function, like this:

```
      ImageButton right_button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.right_arrow);
      right_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("Cube", "Test","HELLO");
       }
      });
```

But when I run my android application and as soon as I click this button, I get this error:

```
    09-11 14:22:37.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1330): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:         com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer
```

I have included classes.jar in my build path also.
Is there anything else I am missing out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It can't find your class UnityPlayer. What else do you expect for an answer.

Comment: Does this help? http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/279581/android-plugin-there-is-no-the-unityplayer-class-i.html

Comment: I am using Eclipse IDE. I managed to get rid of the above error by placing my classes.jar in libs folder and referencing it from there but now I get this error:09-11 19:17:36.339: E/AndroidRuntime(930): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage:(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the class.jar file is in the Build Path of your Project. And if so, check if it is selected (check box is marked).

> Tip: if you get ClassDefNotFound runtime errors (or similar), you might need to perform this extra step:
>
> go to Project > Properties > Java Build Path -> Order and Export tab and check (tick) the classes.jar, Android x.y and Android Dependencies items; then Apply and rebuild the probject.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me the other time too.
I clean, re-link and rebuild my eclipse project. Re-Export my jar file to unity and also restart Unity. Build again and the error is gone.